# Using JQuery/JavaScript to post and then return value using MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC coming frm webforms and I am trying to get my head around AJAX.

I want to click a button in my partial view, call a stored proc which updates a count, and then returns the current total count which is returned from the stored proc.

My Jquery looks like this.

```
function setLikeStatus(id) {
    var param = {
        dayId: id
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/YourDay/LiveHeartClicked",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: param,
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
            alert(xmlHttpRequest + "," + errorText + "," + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

My method looks like this in my controller, I wasn't sure if I sould be using an action result or a JsonResult here. I have tired both but failed.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult LiveHeartClicked(int dayId)
    {
        YourDayEntities3 context = new YourDayEntities3();
        string userId = getUserId();
        var countLikes = context.CreateDayLike(dayId, userId);
        return Json(countLikes);
    }
```

When I click the button I am just getting the response '[object Object]|error|Internal Server Error'.

Any help would be apprieciated.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if you use `ActionResult` or `JsonResult`, although using the more specific `JsonResult` make it clearer just what your method does.

You get an error because the method is marked with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and you have not sent the token.  Remove the attribute from the method. In addition, remove the `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",` option.

You should also use `url: '@Url.Action("LiveHeartClicked", "YourDay")',` to ensure your url's are correctly generated.

Comment: Thats great tank you so much.  This now runs the stored procedure and updates the databse. However I am not getting anything showing in the alert.  when debugging the "data" element is an empty string in Chrome...?

Comment: That just sounds like a problem with the code in your method. Start by just hard coding a value for testing - e.g. `return Json('test data');` to make sure everything else is working

Comment: I've tried that, it works fine on Firefox but not Chrome?

Comment: That makes no sense. There is no difference (and I have just tested it on Chrome and it works fine) Are you getting any other errors in the browser console?

Comment: i've taken the authorize off and now its returning an object.  Although annoyingly its not bringing back the value I want.. but thats another matter I think.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: A problem with you `CreateDayLike()` function I assume :)